# Sending mail to multiple destinations using Exim

Tags: email, exim, centos7

I want to deliver mail to multiple destinations i.e to a php script and to a user's mailbox. I am using Exim for delivering mails. I have changed exim configuration file's Routers and Transport sections as shown below. I have designed a custom transport named send_to_site. I am able to send mail headers to the php script but unable to send email to user's mailbox.
Here is my customized Transport:

######ROUTERS

```
catchall_mail:
  driver = accept
  domains = my.server.com
  transport = send_to_site
```

#####TRANSPORT

```
send_to_site:
    driver = pipe
    command = /home/bin/curl http://my.server.com/mailTest.php --data-urlencode "mail@-"
    user = afterlogic
    group = afterlogic
    return_path_add
    delivery_date_add
    envelope_to_add
```

Where mailTest.php is my php script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I overcome this issue after a long time. In routers section wrote my own custom router that will deliver email to my desired php script. In transport section wrote my own custom transport that will ensure delivery to the desired script using curl. Just wrote the following configurations in my `/etc/exim.cnf` file:

```
############ROUTERS
runscript:
        driver = accept
        transport = run_script
        unseen
        no_expn
        no_verify
############TRANSPORT
run_script:
     debug_print = "T: run_script for $local_part@$domain"
     driver = pipe
     command = /home/bin/curl http://my.domain.com/mailTest.php --data-urlencode $original_local_part@$original_domain
```

Where mailTest.php was my destined script.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create two routers where first should have `unseen` verb. That first router have to pipe message to the script while the second have to perform usual delivery to the user's mailbox.

Sorry for brief answer, I'm posting from phone.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have modified my first router by adding unseen verb and created another router for usual delivery. The case is, now second router is working fine but router dealing with script is not working.